# Website getting lots of visits from this address?

Tags: security

As the title says one of my clients website getting lots of visit from this domain ?

notify.discoverfinancial/notify-Legal_Notice_Splash_Page

What this is all about ?

Is there any security problem ?

Comment: Link removed from question just in case the page is malicious.  I urge people to exercise caution visiting.

Comment: There is not enough information for us to know. We would just be guessing. For example, how are you seeing this traffic? Are you using Google Analytics? Do you see this traffic in your web server logs? Any answer here would be just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Might be ghost referral spam, a blackhat SEO company trying to manipulate your analytics traffic making you search for them.

Comment: Can you explain this more for those users that do not know what you are referring to? For example, what is ghost referral spam? What can be done about it? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no legitimate reason for that page to send requests to your site, it is likely that the page/site is compromised and attempting to attack, infect, or otherwise do something less than desirable.

In these cases, I first make sure my own site has not been compromised and is merely a victim.  Once I'm satisfied with that, I'll make an attempt to contact someone at the attacking site and let them know they may have a problem on their hands.  If necessary, I'll take steps to block the attacking site so as to preserve mine.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar visit to my site from the same referral source [Google Analytics] - dug deep into it.  There is nothing malicious about it. It is a valid visit, but the source has been rewritten to gibberish [it is not a web address]. Probably rewritten to protect the source.

User behaviour on the site reflects a real person, not a bot. Consider the traffic to be from an unknown source.